# How to determine the ad rendered by google publisher tags

Tags: jquery, adsense, google-dfp, adsense-api

Essentially I would like to add some classes to parent elements of a rendered slot depending on the size of ad returned. Is this possible? I see that there is a `googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent` that gives me access to the slot. But from there I am not sure how to determine the element that the slot renders to.

I've done some bookkeeping and have access to the originally defined slots, but comparing them doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They finally exposed a method to get this information: [getSlotElementId](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.Slot_getSlotElementId)

Answer (score 0):

As you are likely aware you can listen for the slotRenderEnded event like the following:

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', slotRendered);
```

Digging through the return event definition, I found the following with get you the DOM element Id where the ad is rendered:

```
function slotRendered(event) {
    if (!event.isEmpty) {
        console.log(event.slot.b.d);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mark this as accepted as it relied on undocumented internals that could be changed at any time.

Comment: I agree, even since I posted this answer it has been changed.